# How to access protected members

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a `MockAlgoController` class which has protected inheritance of `ControllerMockParams`. How to access these protected fields outside, i.e. when asserting in tests?

```
struct ControllerMockParams
{
    int numCtx{0};
    MockAlgo firstAlgo{Interface::first, numCtx};
    MockAlgo secondAlgo{Interface::second, numCtx};
}


class MockAlgoController : protected ControllerMockParams, public AlgoController
{
public:
    MockAlgoController()
        : AlgoController(
              ControllerMockParams::firstAlgo,
              ControllerMockParams::secondAlgo)
    {
    }
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo(), void());
// (...)

}
```

How do I expose the `firstAlgo` and `secondAlgo` so they are accessible outside, i.e. for assertion:

```
EXPECT_CALL(mockAlgoController.firstAlgo, bar()) // bar() is defined in MockAlgo class.
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] so it is clear what are you expecting and what is the problem. Here is [a good starting point](https://godbolt.org/z/Thahrxqc8).

Comment: This page should be helpful to you: http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html

Comment: I think main problem here is understanding how to use dependency injection in C++. Why `ControllerMockParams` is protected when `MockAlgoController` inherits it? What is the scope of problematic `EXPECT_CALL`?

Comment: I have no clue why it's protected haha, this is the legacy code I got from someone and I'm trying to figure out if there was a reason they did it like that.
I would rather cleanly expose firstAlgo/secondAlgo without changing it the inheritace to public if there's a way.

Comment: The protected inheritance means "I don't want these protected members to be visible outside of the class (or it's children) scope". So the short answer is "you can't". Just change the inheritance to public, or IMHO even better: use a composition instead of inheritance to keep `ControllerMockParams`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access protected fields outside you must not use `protected` in the first place. So your code should be like:

```cpp
class MockAlgoController : public ControllerMockParams, public AlgoController
{
public:
    MockAlgoController()
        : AlgoController(
              ControllerMockParams::firstAlgo,
              ControllerMockParams::secondAlgo)
    {
    }
    MOCK_METHOD0(foo(), void());
// (...)
}
```

> When a class uses public member access specifier to derive from a base, all public members of the base class are accessible as public members of the derived class and all protected members of the base class are accessible as protected members of the derived class (private members of the base are never accessible unless friended)

See documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class